# Trying to get JSON response with JavaEE JAX-B, Jasper and Glassfish 4.1.1, but I get error 500

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish

I am learning WebServices with JAX-B and Jasper. I can easily generate XML response, but I want to get JSON response, but I get error 500.

Here is exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException:   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    javax/xml/parsers/ParserConfigurationException
root cause

org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/parsers/ParserConfigurationException
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/parsers/ParserConfigurationException
root cause

 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException not found by org.eclipse.persistence.moxy [228]
```

Full server log: http://pastebin.com/Eq2KbyKJ

Okey, I tried with Tomcat, and it works, it seems that is Glassfish related problem, but I want to use Glassfish as server, since I use EJB in my projects.

Comment: I have this error: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/parsers/ParserConfigurationException and I have to downgrade the glassfish version to 4.1 and it works

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug inside Eclipselink: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=463169 , try upgrading to the latest version?

Comment: @Zookey You could try Payara Server (which is derived from GlassFish) which comes with Eclipselink 2.6.2, so should include this fix. http://www.payara.fish/downloads (note that a new version, 161, is due to be released this week)